# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: java

When I run the following Java program in Netbeans 7.0.1,I get following output:
connection failed
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application. I have 64 bit Windows 7,Ms Access 2007 32 bit,jdk 7 and 32 bit odbc drivers. The same program is working successfully in Notepad then what is the problem in netbeans? I tried with netbeans 7.3.1 also but it didn't work.Please suggest something as I have searched everywhere but couldn't find the solution.

public class Databaseconnectivity {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:eBookStore");
    System.out.println("connected");
    }
catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("connection failed");
            System.out.println(e);
}
```

}
}

Comment: Did you check the JDK used by netbeans?